# Does a return air cavity in a wall need to be lined?

Tags: hvac

What material do I need to place on both side of the wall to return air before I put drywall on top of it?

The return register will be install close to floor level and the wall is made of 2x4 lumber.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming the humidity in your home isn't above average then you don't need to line it with anything. If you wanted to line it with something just for the sake of lining it then you can buy a sheet of sheet metal, cut it to size and bend it into the wall cavity.

Comment: how about covering with Thermopan ?

Comment: Sure, never heard of it but it seems like it's designed for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of sealing a return vent, it is sufficient that the drywall and studs are compressed to create a channel in the wall. No need to caulk the corners, unless there are gaps. No metal lining needed.

For wall to floor transitions you can cut sheet metal to create a custom fitting (box), and seal its metal seams with tape or mastic duct sealant. Lip the metal over the drywall and screw it through the drywall into the stud. The grill will cover this. Screw the other end of the box to the return duct.

Most return in-takes I have seen have no additional sealing. There is a grill in the drywall, a cut-out in the bottom plate, and a blocking horizontal stud behind the drywall above the opening. Sometimes there is a metal return air box, but no additional sealant.

In stead of lining a drywall channel (because it has gaps and cracks), you can use round ducts and squeeze it into an oval or ellipse to fit in the wall cavity (e.g. a 8" duct in 2x4 framing). Since this is more restricting than a rectangular duct/channel formed by the drywall and studs, you'll have to calculate the area of the oval's cross section to make sure is sufficient for the required air flow.

[image]

Image from http://www.ductworkinstallation.com

Answer (score 0):

Drywall itself can act as a return duct. Just install your inlet frame and fit drywall to that. Be sure the entire return path is sealed. The transition from wall to floor cavity, for example, can be troublesome.